# Segmentation fault in Linked List program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This program causes a segmentation fault after the first `printf` statement.
As I know, a segmentation fault in case, memory stack will be full. But in my case there is no recursive program, only after calling a program 4 times.

Please help me understand why this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void append(struct node **, int);
void addatbeg(struct node **,int);
int count(struct node *);
void display(struct node *);
void addafter(struct node **, int,int);

int main()
{
    struct node *q;
    q= NULL; //list is empty

    append(&q,10);
    append(&q,20);
    append(&q,30);
    append(&q,40);

    printf("Now display the contents of the linked list:\n");
    display(q);

    addatbeg(&q,17);
    addatbeg(&q,59);

    printf("after adding the elements in the beginning, new linked list contents are\n");

    display(q);

    addafter(&q,4, 15);
    addafter(&q,7, 25);
    printf("after adding the elements at specified location, list elements are:    \n");
    display(q);

    printf("\n\nCounting of list elements, list has %d elements", count(q));
    return 0;
}

void append(struct node **p, int num)
{
    struct node *temp, *r;
    temp=*p;
    if(*p==NULL)
    //Linked list is empty and the node to be added is the first node
    {
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->link=NULL;
        *p=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->link!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->link;

            r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            r->data=num;
            r->link=NULL;
            temp->link=r;
        }
    }
} 

void addatbeg(struct node **p, int num)
{
    struct node *temp, *r;
    temp=*p;

    r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r->data=num;
    r->link=temp->link;
    *p=r;
}

void addafter(struct node **p, int loc, int num)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp, *r;
    temp=*p;
    //first we will find out the desired loc
    for(i=0; i<loc; i++)
        temp=temp->link;
    //now need to create a new node

    r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r->data=num;
    r->link=temp->link;
    temp->link=r;
}

void display(struct node *p)
{
    while(p!=NULL)
    p=p->link;
    printf("\n%d\t",p->data);
}

int count(struct node *p)
{
    int count=0;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->link;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: And remove the line numbers the next time you post problem code.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that, in `append()`, you are creating new elements in a loop, instead of creating just the one:

```
63    while(temp->link!=NULL)
64    {
65     temp=temp->link;

 r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
68     r->data=num;
69     r->link=NULL;
70     temp->link=r;
71    }
```

However, the immediate cause of the segfault is probably the following:

```
105 void display(struct node *p)
106 {
107   while(p!=NULL)
108   p=p->link;
109   printf("\n%d\t",p->data);
110 }
```

Here, the `printf()` needs to be inside the loop. Your current code doesn't actually print the elements, and tries to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can much likely come from your display function. You probably have forgotten brackets in the while.

To have some really good hints about the memory allocation errors, and more generally anything you are doing wrong with your memory, you should be using `valgrind` (if you are on a linux distribution).

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
void display(struct node *p)
 {
   while(p!=NULL)
   p=p->link;
   printf("\n%d\t",p->data);
 }
```

when the loop ends p will be NULL.
So you get segmentation fault.

Change it to

```
while(p->link!=NULL){
   ...
}
```

Comment: That was a typo. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Line 20-22:

You are passing the adress of a null pointer to `append`, causing undefined behaviour.

Possible fix:

```
20 q = malloc(sizeof q);
   *q = NULL;
```

There also seems to be other issues with your code, so check the other answers and comments as well.